# Flash message not showing in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on nextjs,I am integrating "newsletter",Whenever my response is true
then validation message showing correct(if condition),but only show one time for 5 seconds,and whenever i am getting error then validation
message(else condition) not working,means "error" message not showing
Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FlashMessage from 'react-flash-message';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const Subscribe = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            
            const emails = email;
            event.preventDefault();
            
            const res = await fetch('https://example.com/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email='+emails);
            const data = await res.json();
            const status = data["status"];
            const message = data["msg"];
            if (status === "false") {
                setError(error);
              } else {
                setSuccess(message);
              }
};
    const changeEmail = (event) => {
        const email = event.target.value;
        setEmail(email);
    }
```

And i tried with following code for display "success" or "error" message

```
{success && (
                    <FlashMessage duration={5000}>
                     <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <strong>{success}</strong>
                        </div> 
                    </FlashMessage>
                    
                )}          
                {error && (
                    <FlashMessage duration={5000}>
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>{error}</strong>
                        </div> 
                    </FlashMessage>
                    
                )}
```

Comment: can you share the response body ? data['status'] could be false, instead of "false" as a string

Comment: @user54321: api response is "{"status":true,"msg":"Email saved successfully"} "

OR 

"{"status":false,"msg":"Email already exist"}"

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, you're comparing `false === "false"` and `true === "false"` - both of which are never true. You should change the code to `if (status === false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the API response is `{"status":false,"msg":"Email already exist"}`,`data['status']` needs to be compared with the boolean value.

`===` checks for both value and the type ([MDN reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)). In this case it always returns false because you are comparing a string with boolean.

If you change the comparison to `if( status === false )` then it should work